# Движок для сайта на ruby или php?

Tags: php, ruby

Выбор движка для сайта ruby (ruby on rails) или php - какие плюсы-минусы у этих вариантов? Подскажите, какие могут быть принципиальные моменты при выборе? Тематика сайта - недвижимость. Какие будут плюсы-минусы, именно связанные с выбором движка?

Comment: Ну php - это не движок, а язык программирования. ruby-on-rails - первый раз слышу про него.

Comment: @Ёхарный Вы написали самый полезный и корректный ответ, который я видел.

Comment: @Ёхарный Ruby on Rails - это аналог Zend Framework.

Comment: Это не движки.

Comment: Эх, берите рельсы, не пожалеете ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Лично мне** больше нравятся рельсы, а пых я почему то сразу невзлюбил.

Можно писать качественные (как собственно и некачественные) сайты с использованием любых языков и технологий. Я бы советовал просто взять hello_world по какому-нибудь php-framework'у (гуглите Yii, Symfony) и, соответственно, RubyOnRails. В процессе реализации и поймете что больше нравится.

Плюсы рельс (на мой взгляд опять-таки)

- более приятный язык разработки
- большое наличие gem'ов - gem что-то вроде dll, so, etc. С их помощью можно решить почти любую проблему
- легко разворачивается на апаче с использованием гема Passenger

Минусы

- нужен выделенный сервер

*Все написано на правах сугубо личного субъективного мнения*

Comment: Это только ваше личное мнение, все необъективно

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 именно так, и я об этом трижды написал в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы программист и ваша задача - быстрее создать сайт, то берите то что лучше знаете. Если ничего не знаете, но хочется сделать быстрее - берите PHP c Zend/Yii/др, если хочется сделать и научиться чему-то - берите Rails и учите Ruby.

Если вы не программист - то выбирайте то, на чём сможете найти программистов. Найдёте хороших Rails-программеров - берите Rails, но обычно проще найти PHPшников...

Так что если есть цель - надо преследовать эту цель, а фреймворки - вторично. А если хочется поholywarить - то я пас...

Comment: Спасибо, пришел примерно к таким же выводам в итоге!

Answer (score 1):

Тема холиварная, поэтому просто приведу ссылки на известные фреймворки `PHP` и сайт со сравнением их возможностей:

- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) *(мой выбор для нескольких проектов)*
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)

Сайт, где можно сравнить их возможности - [**phpframeworks.com**](http://www.phpframeworks.com/)

---

`RoR` - это standalone фреймворк на `Ruby`, касательно выбора `RoR vs PHP` могу посоветовать одну неплохую [**заметку.**](http://romanvbabenko.blogspot.com/2009/03/ror-vs-php.html)

Comment: Плохая заметка, на самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

Как ответили выше, это не движки а языки программиравания(RoR насколько помню это фреймверк) Связка php + mysql подойдет под ваши цели !

Comment: **Вы тоже туда же?**

Фраза

> выбор движка для сайта ruby (ruby on rails) или php`

очевидно, же, подразумевает выбор между фреймворками на `PHP` и рельсами, которые сами по себе являются фреймворком.

Comment: php - это не фреймворк!!!!